# Document Path as View Column

Tags: calculated-column

I have a library that contains documents and folder. I would like to have a view on this library that shows every document and includes the path to that document.

For instance the following:

```
Folder1
-Folder2
--Doc1
-Folder3
--Doc2
--Folder4
---Doc3
```

Would show up in the View as:

```
Folder1/Folder2 Doc1
Folder1/Folder3 Doc2
Folder1/Folder3/Folder4 Doc3
```

What kind of column can I add to include this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that a calculated item will work in this case as any column that references the file path is not available in the calculated column arsenal. You could use a workflow on item creation and item edit to update a text field leveraging some of the internal fields (like Server Relative URL, Path, or URL Path).